# Как получить динамическую цену в php

Tags: php, javascript

Делаю форму онлайн бронирования отелей и столкнулся с проблемой: у меня добавлена функция автоматического подсчета стоимости в зависимости от выбора клиента, все это выводиться в тег span, никак не могу вытащить конечную сумму в обработчик.

Скрипт подсчета:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        function calc() {

            var bookingInputRoom1 = document.getElementById("bookingInputRoom1");
            var bookingInputRoom2 = document.getElementById("bookingInputRoom2");
            var col1 = document.getElementById("col1");
            var col2 = document.getElementById("col2");
            var result = document.getElementById("result");

            var price = 0;
            price += (col1.checked == true) ? parseInt(bookingInputRoom1) : 0;
            price += (col2.checked == true) ? parseInt(bookingInputRoom2) : 0;

            result.innerHTML =  price;  
        }
</script>
```

Вот так вывожу стоимость:

```
Стоимость бронирования: <span id="result" value="0" name="summa">0</span> руб
```

Как правильно выводить сумму так, чтобы потом можно было отправить в обработчик? Заранее спасибо!

Comment: Прежде всего что такое result? Нигде не объявлено, ни на что не ссылается.

Comment: И скорее всего забыли извлечь данные из инпутов document.getElementById("bookingInputRoom2").value

Comment: Отредактировал, просто забыл тут объявить result, в полной версии все норм. Дело в том, что цена у меня выводиться отлично, не могу я ее в обработчик отправить

Comment: Правило №1: "Никогда не доверяй клиенту". Это значит, что полученная сумма не должна отправляться на сервер. Сервер исходя из каких-то данных должен её сосчитать. Даже если логика дублируется у клиента.

Comment: У меня 6 отелей по 7 номеров + цена отличается от кол людей + у каждого номера есть разные доп услуги: тренажерный зал, доп место и т.д. Даже не представляю как выносить эти данные и потом сосчитать их. Ну точнее сделать это можно, но геморроя уж очень много. Проще вытащить конечный результат =)

Comment: проще, но не безопаснее. передавайте какие-нибудь идентификаторы выбранных полей на сервер, и там считайте.